# Pass a list as a parameter to JPQL named query not working

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, jpql, weblogic12c

I have an JPQL named query declared this way:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Client.findByInternalIds", query =
     "select o from Client o where o.internalId in (:internalIds)")
```

Here, `:internalIds` is supposed to be a list i pass as a parameter to the named query on runtime. There problem is whenever i try to do this:

```
@Override
public List<Client> getClientsByInternalIds(List<Integer> internalIds) {
    TypedQuery<Client> nq = em.createNamedQuery("Client.findByInternalIds", Client.class);
    nq.setParameter("internalIds", internalIds);
    return nq.getResultList();
}
```

I get basically this error (exception)

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You have attempted to set a value of type class java.util.ArrayList
>   for parameter internalIds with expected type of class
>   java.lang.Integer from query string select o from Client o where
>   o.internalId in (:internalIds)

I searched around the internet for a solution, and all seem to say that my syntax is correct, so can anyone help me figure out this please? Thank you.

FYI, using WebLogic 12c, with EclipseLink.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually wasn't right on the syntax, after many and many tries, the simple solution was to remove the brackets on the `internalIds` paramter in the `@NamedQuery` definition.

So the `@NamedQuery` becomes this:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Client.findByInternalIds", query =
     "select o from Client o where o.internalId in :internalIds")
```

And it works!